# Unable to update after installing pcsx2 from PPA

Tags: updates

I am having some problems fully updating my system after installing pcsx2. Now this shows up:

```
Err:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu jammy Release
```

Comment: The PPA mentioned in the error message hasn't been updated since 2018. Obviously it has no contents for a Ubuntu release of April 2022! Remove it.

Comment: BTW, you don't need a PPA to install pcsx2. If you actually did install it the system got it from the Ubuntu official repositories, not from that PPA, obviously.

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party software sources, so all security & validation checks are the responsibility of the end-user. Did you check it?

Comment: Related: [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629)